# Pasting content of CSV files into an excel sheet in python 2.5

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-2.x

So basically I got an xlsm document, it contains a sheet "data" and a graph, the graph is generated from data.

I have 5 CSV files.

I need to erase the content of data, then fill it with the 5 CSV files.

Is it possible to do without putting my csv file in an array and writing them line per line (very time consuming).

Can I just open my CSV files and sort of paste them into the data sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just open CSV files in Excel, and you can join your CSV files into one larger one with

```
my_files = ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'file_3.csv', 'file_4.csv', 'file_5.csv']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as oo:
    for file in my_files:
        with open(file, 'r') as io:
            oo.write(io.readlines())
```

you can then open `output.csv` in excel.

If you don't want to manually list all your input files, you could use `glob`

```
>>> my_files = glob.glob('file_*.csv')
>>> my_files
... ['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'file_3.csv', 'file_4.csv', 'file_5.csv']
```

There is even an Excel read / write python module [here](http://www.python-excel.org/). You could use it to write directly to an Excel file:

```
import xlwt

w = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('First sheet')

i = 0
for file in my_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as fo:
    for line in fo.readlines():
       for j, col in enumerate(line.split(',')):
           ws.write(i, j, col)
           i += 1
```

Comment: Nope, the excel file already exist, I have to do this with python I cannot open by hand the excel file (it's an automated reporting system), maybe I did not understood you

Comment: Use `xlwt` to open the Excel file.